# How to eliminate certain (non system) headers from dependency files(.d)?

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

We link in a library(TAO) which is composed of many header files.

Every time I run the pre-processor command on a cpp file( **g++ -MM $< $@** ), these library files are automatically included in every .d file generated.

**These are obviously not system files and almost never change** as far as we're concerned, so I would like to eliminate them from my .d files.

**Short of filtering out these header files using sed, is there any built in way to accomplish this?**

Comment: Assuming there are in their own directories, you may use `-isystem` to treat them as system directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may instruct gcc to consider some path as system headers with `-isystem`; and `g++ -MM` ignore system-headers.